# stop during import using sqoop

Tags: import, command, sqoop

I am using sqoop to import data from MS sql to HBase. If there is some error, is that possible to use some command to cancel the import manually before it terminates itself? If it is possible, which command should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ctrl+C terminate HBase and re-enter hbase will work.